# How to check next testcase then browser.verify.ok fails

Tags: nightwatch.js

```
module.exports = {
    'test' : function (browser) {

        browser
            .url("someurl");

        browser.getTitle((title) => {
            browser.verify.ok(title.trim().length !== 0, "Title is not empty");
        });

        browser.expect.element('h1').text.to.not.equal('');
    }
};
```

If `browser.verify.ok` fails testcase stops `browser.expect.element('h1').text.to.not.equal('');` is not running.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to continue running tests after an assertion fails, set `abortOnAssertionFailure: false` in `globals.js` file. Reference: https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/blob/master/lib/settings/defaults.js#L19